# Google maps background is not rendered but marker pins are placed

Tags: android, google-maps

My goal is to place markers on a map. I retrieve the latitude and longitude coordinates I need from a web service that is currently not public and is only available in my company's internal environment (VPN).

I wrote a simple logic for this:

1. Using `SupportMapFragment`.
2. Getting a GoogleMap reference in a `onMapReady` callback.
3. Adding markers to the map reference received in step 2.

But I am seeing the following output:

[image]

I am able to place markers on the map but the map's background is not rendering, I can only see empty tiles. If I zoom out until I reach the highest zoom level, then the map (of the entire world) becomes visible.

It might be the internal environment proxy, but I am able to see maps in other applications, like uber or BOFA in that same environment.

I can definitely say it is not the API key or a configuration issue, as I am able to place markers on the map.

What could be the problem?

Comment: what do you get in logcat ?

Comment: seems like map data is not being delivered. have you tried switching network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everyone for looking in to it and trying to help.

I found solution for it. When i comment following line
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);

everything is working fine. May be certificate downloaded stopping google to download data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Google Maps in the developer console? See https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-google-maps-for-android-basics--cms-24635